# How can I do full text searches on files and have a preview?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, software-rec, finder, spotlight

On Windows XP I used Google Desktop Search which provided full text searches on files and emails with a preview of results, like a Google search. It indexed files when needed.

I'm looking for something like this on OS X Snow Leopard. Spotlight and Finder search don't produce a preview. Google desktop isn't the same thing on the Mac.

What can I use?

Comment: i think [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) has this feature, when doing a search you can press spacebar to look at a preview

Comment: did you try QSB ?

Comment: LaunchBar and QSB, don't seem to do this, here's a screenshot of what I'm looking for http://www.google.co.uk/m/search?q=google+desktop&pbx=1&aq=1&oq=google%2520de&aqi=g6-k10d1t0&fkt=1218&fsdt=9712&cqt=&rst=&htf=&his=&maction=&site=images&gl=uk&source=mog&csll=&action=&ltoken=16295913#i=28

Comment: Google Desktop Requires Mac OS X 10.4, For 10.5+ we recommend Google Quick Search Box

Comment: @Jules Yeah, they ditched that in favor of the QSB. The feature you need has been [requested for a long time](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/issues/detail?id=1049&q=preview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) but I don't think there are huge changes to come for the QSB.

Comment: Thanks @slhck, I did find a page saying that they are doing it, but are having to develop it from the ground up. All I really want is to do a search and see a preview of whats found with surounding text. I've seacrhed extensivly since I posted here, but can't find anything close to this. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Jules Not really, I've been using QSB and their likes (Quicksilver) for quite some time now but haven't really needed that feature yet. Wondering though if somebody finds something.

Comment: You can get something a bit like this by viewing Spotlight search results in the Cover Flow view -- it doesn't tile the previews like you want, but you can skim through them quickly, and use spacebar to get an expanded (Quick Look) preview.

Comment: It's still not as easy as seeing a short preview for each result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite the same thing, but you can use the Finder's search window (Option-Cmd-Space) and use Quick Look as your preview. When you have a Quick Look preview open, you can use the Up and Down arrow keys to scroll through the results without having to close and reopen the preview.

Comment: It's still not as easy as seeing a short preview for each result

Answer (score 0):

OSX Lion provides quick look like previews right in the spotlight menu in the top right corner.

And choosing "Show All" brings up a finder window that offers quick look via space bar.

Answer (score 0):

[Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) might be what you're looking for:

[image]

It's coded for Linux but should run fine under [Macports](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts).

You can find more information on the installation [here](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/download.html).